# Archive directory system with compression for subdirectories - dar?

Tags: backup, tar, archiving

I have a large (~100GB uncompressed) collection of files that I want to store in < 2GB chunks for backup on a Windows Server based storage system. I'm running Ubuntu on my workstation.

The data sets are collected in subdirectories, with a tiered type of structure. (e.g., directory A contains three subdirectories 1, 2, 3, which each contain maybe 30ish subdirectories, which each contain 6 or 7 files, with the same names (in each subdirectory))

`tar` will compress and archive my data, but if I want to access individual sections, it's pretty painful. It's also slow, and if I use compression, I have to uncompress before I can extract individual directories (afaik)

This would be using something like:

```
tar -cf mySuperStructure.tar;
split -b 1024M mySuperStructure.tar mySuperStructure.tar.part- ;
gzip mySuperStructure.tar.part-* ;
```

or similar - I know tar has a `-z` option, but I think this might be problematic when using `split`? Likewise, I believe there is an option to split `tar` archives, possibly with compression, but the files are split in unhelpful ways (Perhaps this is the best solution, if so - please advise)

Alternatively, `dar` will compress on a file by file level, allowing a `-m` option to specify a minimum size. This would be ideal, but for the large number of files making it take a long time to compress and archive the setup. The lowest level directories are ~70MB in size, so compressing these would be useful (and I suspect faster, since fewer compression operations?)

Can I specify the compression of the subdirectories individually, without individual files being compressed? Would this be any faster if I could?

A manual implementation might look like:

```
for levelA in $(ls); do
cd levelA;
    for subdirectoryCase in $(ls); do
    cd subdirectoryCase;
        for subdirSmall in $(ls); do
        gzip subdirSmall;
        done
    cd ..;
    tar -cf $subdirectoryCase.tar $subdirectoryCase;
    gzip $subdirectoryCase.tar;
    done
cd ..;
tar -cf $levelA.tar $levelA;
gzip $levelA.tar;
done

tar -cf superStructure.tar levelA1.tar levelA2.tar levelA3.tar;
gzip superStructure.tar;
```

but this seems like it might be micromanaging to a horrible level (but that might still be best, I don't know?) `dar` could be substituted for `tar` throughout, and `split` could be used perhaps before the final `gzip`, assuming that the earlier gzip'd files were sufficiently small (which they won't be, but that's presumably possible to deal with in a similar manner)

Comment: why not store them on a Windows compressed volume without archiving?

Comment: @Keltari - not sure I understand? I'm assuming from the words in your sentence you mean something like, place the files, then squash them, but I can only upload individual files to the server, and I don't know about 'compressed volumes'. I really have no idea about Windows filesystems or storage :/

Comment: If you just want to explore and micromanage your files inside archives, maybe [AVFS](http://www.boomerangsworld.de/cms/avfs/) may interest you?